# CSS hamburger menu stick to top after scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I have a mobile navigation menu which I have positioned below the banner of my page using top property of CSS and when I scroll down the menu stays in the same position (51vh from the top), I want the menu to stick to the top of the page after I scroll down and the banner goes out of view. This is my code :

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Align</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile-menu.css">
</head>
<body>
      
    <div id="banner">
        <canvas id='c' width="100%" height="35%"></canvas>  
        <img src="images/Main Banner.png" class="img-fluid" id="cover" alt="..."> 
        
        <img src="images/logo.png"  id="logo" alt="...">

        <div id="pc-nav" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-border nav-shadow" id="main-nav">                
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand nb" href="index.html">HOME</a> -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right flex-grow-1 mr-right1" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-5 flex-nowrap align-items-end">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="therapists.php">Find Therapists</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="blogs.html">Community Content</a>
                        <a class="nav-link me-5" href="interns.php">Join us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="outer-menu sticky-top" style="z-index: 11;">
            <input class="checkbox-toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <div class="hamburger">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <div>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="therapists.php">Find Therapists</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blogs.html">Community Content</a></li>
                    <li><a href="interns.php">Join us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
           
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid px-5 pt-1 " id="content" style="position: relative; z-index: 9;">
        <div class="row gx-1">
            <div class="col" >
                <div>
                    <div class="p-5 mb-4 aasha-red-bg rounded-3">
                        <div class="container-fluid py-5 animatedParent animateOnce" data-sequence='250' data-appear-top-offset='-337'>
                            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='1'>About Align</h1>
                            <p class="fs-4 text-white animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. Pellentesque bibendum leo quis leo rutrum faucibus. Aenean facilisis pharetra lorem, non porta ipsum imperdiet in. Etiam vel suscipit felis, eget ultricies augue. Aenean libero justo, malesuada ac libero sed, tincidunt cursus orci. Suspendisse iaculis commodo eleifend. Aliquam.</p>
                            <a href="more-about-us.html" class="btn inverse-main-btn btn-lg animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='3'>More about us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
            
                <div>
                    <div class="p-5 mb-4 rounded-3">
                        <div class="container-fluid py-5 animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-337' data-sequence='250'>
                            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold aasha-red-text animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='1'>Support Group</h1>
                            <p class="col-md-8 fs-4 animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. Pellentesque bibendum leo quis leo rutrum faucibus.</p>
                            <a href="support-group.html" class="btn main-btn btn-lg animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='3'>Find out more</a>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div>
                    <div class="p-5 mb-4 rounded-3">
                        <div class="container-fluid py-5 animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-337' data-sequence='250'>
                            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='1'>Psych, Resources and Other Stuff</h1>
                            <p class="col-md-8 fs-4 animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. Pellentesque bibendum leo quis leo rutrum faucibus. Aenean facilisis pharetra lorem, non porta ipsum imperdiet in. Etiam vel suscipit felis, eget ultricies augue. Aenean libero justo, malesuada ac libero sed, tincidunt cursus orci. Suspendisse iaculis commodo eleifend. Aliquam.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          <div class="col-1">  
          </div>

          <div class="col" id="feed">

            <div class="feedposts" >
                <img src="images/blog1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail feed-image" id="" alt="..." >
                <div class="animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-137' data-sequence='250'>   
                    <p class="fs-6 blog-author animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='1'> Memento | June 6th, 2021 | 2 min read </p>
                    <h3 class="animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                    <p class="fs-5 blog-text animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='3'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn main-btn btn-lg animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='4'>Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
           
            <div class="feedposts" >
                <img src="images/blog2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail feed-image" id="" alt="..." >
                <div class="animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-137' data-sequence='250'>   
                    <p class="fs-6 blog-author animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='1'> Memento | June 6th, 2021 | 2 min read </p>
                    <h3 class="animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                    <p class="fs-5 blog-text animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='3'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn main-btn btn-lg animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='4'>Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>   
            
            <div class="feedposts" >
                <img src="images/blog3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail feed-image" id="" alt="..." >
                <div class="animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-137' data-sequence='250'>   
                    <p class="fs-6 blog-author animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='1'> Memento | June 6th, 2021 | 2 min read </p>
                    <h3 class="animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                    <p class="fs-5 blog-text animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='3'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at leo lobortis, luctus dui a, gravida orci. </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn main-btn btn-lg animated fadeInRightShort" data-id='4'>Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>   
    
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> 

    <div id="footer" style="position: relative; z-index: 9;">
        <img src="images/footer.png" class="img-fluid" id="footerbanner" alt="...">  
    </div>

    <div class="footer-basic" style="position: relative; z-index: 9;">
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-links">
                <div><a href="for-professionals.php">For Therapists</a></div>
                <div><a href="interns.html">For Volunteers</a></div>
                <div><a href="content_creators.html">For Content Creators</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="socials">
                <div class="socials-text">Socials</div>
                <div class="socials-icons">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tryalign/" class="social-icons" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/the-aasha-initiative/" class="social-icons" class="social-lin" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright">ALIGN © 2021</div>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <script src="js/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/brush.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>                        


</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300');
 .flex-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.outer-menu a, .outer-menu a a:visited, .outer-menu a a:hover, .outer-menu a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.outer-menu h1 {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.outer-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51vh;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:before, .outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
    opacity: 0;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu {
    pointer-events: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition-duration: .75s;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .4s ease .4s;
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:hover + .hamburger {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.outer-menu .hamburger {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    background: rgba(100, 102, 231, 0.75);
    border-radius: 0 .12em .12em 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow .4s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.outer-menu .hamburger > div {
    position: relative;
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.outer-menu .hamburger > div:before, .outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: inherit;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
    top: 10px;
}

.outer-menu .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541);
}

.outer-menu .menu > div {
    width: 200vw;
    height: 200vw;
    color: #FEFEFE;
    background: rgba(242, 31, 66, 0.754);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    flex: none;
    transform: scale(0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 90vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color .4s ease;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #e5e5e5;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-menu .menu > div > div > ul > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -0.15em;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    transition: width .4s ease;
}
```

Also, I have a different navigation bar for large screens which gets hidden for mobile and tablet devices and my mobile menu/navbar gets hidden for large screens and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

use `position: sticky;` property. It lets the choosen elements with this property to follow your scrolling trough the page.

Comment: I am using `position: sticky;` and that makes it visible even after scrolling, but it's about 50% from the top of the screen because of `top: 51vh;` that I am using on `.outer-menu` to place it below the banner. I need a way to make it stick to the top right of the page.